# Задали вопрос на собеседование

Tags: java

Задали вопрос на собеседовании в чом его суть ?

```
 public class Test1 {
    public float aMethod(float a, float b) {
    }

   

}
```

Какие из перечисленных методов можно добавить в строку 4 класса Test1?

```
    A. public int aMethod(int a, int b) { }

    B. public float aMethod(float a, float b) { }

    C. public float aMethod(float a, float b, int c) throws Exception { }

    D. public float aMethod(float c, float d) { }

    E. private float aMethod(int a, int b, int c) { }
```

Comment: Мы не видим где тут 4 строка. Возможно, вопрос про перегрузку методов. Тогда, наверное, подойдёт вариант `A`

Comment: Суть в понимании что такое перегрузка методов. A, C, E - подойдут.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 5):

В JAVA возможно использовать методы с одним и тем же именем, но с разными типами и/или количеством параметров. Это называется перегрузка методов (method overloading)

- A, так как этот метод принимает параметры иного типа
- C, добавлен еще один параметр
- E, добавлен еще один параметр и все теперь int

А вот различие в типе возвращаемого значения не имеют никакого значения

Comment: Отдельного упоминания заслуживает сигнатура метода и различия в именах параметров, которые ни на что не влияют, из-за чего не подходит вариант D.